# $\lim_{a\to 0}\|\tau_a f-f\|_\infty=0$, then there is some $f=g$ a.e. such that $g\in BUC(\Bbb R^n,E)$

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

I want to check my proof. Let $\tau_a:E^{\Bbb R^n}\to E^{\Bbb R^n}$ such that $\tau_a f(x)=f(x-a)$ for all $x\in\Bbb R^n$ and any chosen $f\in E^{\Bbb R^n}$. Then the exercise says

> Prove that if $\lim_{a\to 0}\|\tau_a f-f\|_\infty=0$ then there is some $g=f$ almost everywhere such that $g$ is bounded and uniformly continuous.

Here $\|{\cdot}\|_\infty$ is the seminorm of the space $\mathcal L_\infty(\Bbb R^n,\lambda_n,E)$, where $\lambda_n$ is the Lebesgue measure and $E$ is a Banach space. My proof:

The statement to be proved is not true in it generality. Let $f(x):=x$ (we choose here $E=\Bbb R^n$), then clearly $\|\tau_a f-f\|_\infty=|a|$ so $\lim_{a\to 0}\|\tau_af-f\|_\infty=0$, however $f$ is not essentially bounded, so I assume that we need the assumption that $f\in\mathcal L_\infty(\Bbb R^n,\lambda_n,E)$.

If $f\in\mathcal L_\infty(\Bbb R^n,\lambda_n,E)$ then clearly $f$ is essentially bounded, so there is some $g\in\mathcal L_\infty(\Bbb R^n,\lambda_n,E)$ such that $f=g$ a.e. such that $g$ is bounded.

Now suppose that $f$ is not uniformly continuous a.e., then for any chosen null set $N$ we have that
$$
\exists \epsilon_0>0,\;\forall \delta>0,\;\exists x,y\in N^\complement:|x-y|<\delta\,\land\,|f(x)-f(y)|\ge\epsilon_0\tag1
$$
Then setting $|x-y|=|a|$ we find that
$$
\exists \epsilon_0>0,\;\forall \delta>0,\;\exists a\in\Bbb R^n,\;\exists x_a\in N^\complement:|a|<\delta\;\land\;|\tau_a f(x_a)-f(x_a)|\ge\epsilon_0\tag2
$$
But then we find that $\|\tau_a f-f\|_\infty\ge\epsilon_0$ for arbitrarily small $|a|>0$ in any chosen subset of $\Bbb R^n$ with null complement, what contradicts the assumption that $\lim_{a\to 0}\|\tau_a f-f\|_\infty=0$, so we conclude that $f$ is also uniformly continuous a.e.

Now we need to show that if $f$ is uniformly continuous a.e. then there is some $g=f$ a.e. such that $g$ is uniformly continuous. Let $N$ the null set such that $f$ is uniformly continuous in $N^\complement$ and suppose that $\overline{N^\complement}\neq\Bbb R^n$, then $(\overline{N^\complement})^\complement$ is open and not empty, and because the Lebesgue measure is massive then $\mu((\overline{N^\complement})^\complement)>0$ what contradicts the completeness of the Lebesgue measure because $(\overline{N^\complement})^\complement\subset N$, hence $N^\complement$ is dense in $\Bbb R^n$.

Then by a previous result I know that $f|_{N^\complement}$ can be extended continuously on $N$, so we can conclude that such $g\in BUC(\Bbb R^n,E)$ exists.$\Box$

Comment: This looks OK to me.

Comment: Hey!! :). Can I ask you something (let's delete this comments then): what is the meaning of `a.e.`? o.O

Comment: @manooooh it means "almost everywhere". In measure theory it means that a property holds a.e. if it holds in all it domain except at some subset with measure zero. In measure theory a set of measure zero is also called a null set.

Comment: Thank you! I thought there was a typo. The property is only one way or, instead, can yo prove the other implication?

Comment: @manooooh yes, the other implication is also true. If $\|\tau_a f-f\|\ge\epsilon_0$ then $f$ cannot be uniformly continuous a.e.